# how to control the scrollbar in overflow scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, overflow

I was building something that uses the same idea that [goat.com](http://goat.com) uses in their sliding section [image]

what they did was use `overflow-x: scroll;` which I do too but I'm not sure how can I use js/react to control it like that and go forward and backward in it.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get the result where you can scroll horizontally using a mouse you can use pure css with it. Read the example bellow.

1. Set up the container

   Make a `<div>`, and make a bunch of child elements.

   In this example, our side-scrolling container will be 300px wide, with 8 items of 100×100px each. These are arbitrary sizes; they could be anything.

   ```
   <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper squares">
     <div>item 1</div>
     <div>item 2</div>
     <div>item 3</div>
     <div>item 4</div>
     <div>item 5</div>
     <div>item 6</div>
     <div>item 7</div>
     <div>item 8</div>
   </div>
   ```

   The height of the container will become the "width" and vice-versa. So below, the "width" of our container will be 300px:

   ```
   .horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
     width: 100px;
     height: 300px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   ```

   Now the children:

   ```
   .horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
   }
   ```
2. Rotating the container

   Now we rotate the container -90 degrees with a CSS transform. And there you have it: a horizontal scroller.

   ```
   .horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
     ...
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
     transform-origin: right top;
   }
   ```

There’s just one tiny issue: our children have rotated too, and now anything within is on its side.

3. Rotate the children back upright
   How would we go about getting the children upright again? Rotate them back using another, opposite CSS transform.

   ```
   .horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div {
     ...
     transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform-origin: right top;
   }
   ```
4. Fixing the positioning

   It’s starting to look alright, but there are still some issues.

   By rotating the wrapper using the top right as an anchor point, our left side has shifted by the width of the container. If you find this difficult to understand, just put your finger on the top right corner of a page and rotate it. The solution: shift it back with translateY.

   Better. But the first item is still missing, due to the same phenomenon happening to the items. We could fix this by giving the first child a top margin of its width or by translating all items the same way we did the wrapper. The easiest way I’ve found though is to add a top padding to the wrapper equal to the item width, creating a kind of buffer for the items.

   ```
   .horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
     ...
     transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
     ...
   }
   ```

You can check this sample code:

- https://codepen.io/pieter-biesemans/pen/BQBWXX
- https://codepen.io/pieter-biesemans/pen/zoOvMY